# Chrome doesn`t automatically indicate to the user that Progressive Web App is installable

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps

I created a PWA written in Flutter. Chrome and Safari doesn`t automatically indicate to the user that Progressive Web App is installable. In Chrome I have to open the 3 vertical dots in order to install.
What shall I do in order to have a notification to the user to install the app?
Note: I have to say that based on running a Lighthouse audit the Pwa is installable.

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: Are you testing on a machine/device that you have used before? If so, it is possible you have not cleared out everything from previous testing/installs. Try on a fresh device/machine to quickly check this.

Comment: Hi Mathias, I tried in a new device (an Android mobile) and it works. If you have any idea on how to clean everything from the previous install I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Settings>Privacy>Clear browsing Data> On android there is an "All time" option when clearing the cache - use that. Also, make sure you have looked through your app icons and dragged your app to delete trash can if there.